# delete db entry using js

Tags: php

i have three file...
1st index.tpl.php
code of this is

```
<td>
<input type="button" name="checkbox" value="delete" onclick="selectAccess('<?php echo __('are you sure you want to delete data')?>','<?php echo $sGroups['id_user']; ?>')">
</td>
```

2nd is common.js

```
function selectAccess(message,AccessId){

   var answer = confirm(message)
   alert(AccessId);
   if (answer)
   {
     $.ajax({
      url: SITE_URL + '/users/delete',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 
                'ID':AccessId

            },

      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
     });
   }
}
```

here its not working..... plese advice me where is mistake
thnks...

Comment: The only answer you can get with such a vague "it's not working" problem is "well it's probably broken somehow". Are you getting a JS error? Are you getting an error in your PHP (which is completely missing in your question, even though it is tagged "php")? Are you getting no errors, but no update in the database either?

Comment: apply break points and find out the error line. is that alert in beginning working?

Answer (score 0):

- do you see the confirm box ? (then click event was rightly handled and processed)
- Is SITE_URL defined somewhere and do you see the XHR request fire ?
  (then ajax call is good)